# Forwarding SMS-iMessages from a contact to another automatically

Tags: iphone, sms

s it possible to forward messages from one contact to another automatically?

My wife and I are sharing a prepaid bank card, which is registered to my phone number. When you want to make an online purchase with it, bank sends a 3d confirmation code to my phone in an SMS. Code has a short validity period, so sometimes I'm not around/available to forward it to her. Is it possible to forward messages from my phone to hers automatically?

I tried messing with messaging settings and searched the app store, couldn't find something that does this.

Btw my phone model is iPhone 5s.